# Class path in Neo4j unmanaged extension

Tags: java, neo4j

Sorry if a naive Java question. I've been working in a Neo4j unmanaged extension (https://github.com/toniher/neo4j-biorelation) and it worked well as far as class path used was under *org.neo4j*, e.g.

```
org.neo4j.parent.parentextension
```

However if using another one:

```
cat.cau.biorelation.rest
```

I got the following problem when starting the server

```
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
cat.cau.biorelation.rest
des. 02, 2014 10:17:05 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
des. 02, 2014 10:17:05 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules <init>
SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
```

So, is *org.neo4j* mandatory or should I define something elsewhere for avoiding this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(sic) fixed typo. Bad package definition. https://github.com/toniher/neo4j-biorelation/commit/3f2704f660bf0ac0e3260539801f28959705c997